# Implementing multiple account access to a single feature with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm creating a web app with Firebase on the back end where multiple users can access a feature, created by a root user.

The real-time db structure looks like this

```
project 
    project id
       userID:userID of the user who created it
       meta:other information about the project ...
       team: 
           memberid1:{}
           memberid2:{}
```

Until now, I've only allowed the root user to access the project. To do this, I've used the `ref.orderByChild('userID').equalsTo(userID of user logged in)` method of firebase js sdk to determine if the logged in user can access it because userID is a direct child of projectID.

But now, I want to allow multiple users to access a project. For this I've added a new child called team under which members can be added. But I can't use the aforementioned method to determine if a user who's logged in can access the project because the `memberID` is a grandchild of the project and hence `orderByChild` chained with `equalTo` won't work.

How could I do this with the DB structure as I stated above, and if it's not, how could I do this with a change in DB structure.

Comment: Your current structure makes it easy to find the members of a team. But it doesn't make it easy to find the teams that someone is a member of. To easily allow that you'll need to add an additional top-level list (e.g. `userTeams`), where you track the teams/team ids of each user. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value) or the one I gave two hours ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282697/calling-a-child-inside-2-levels-of-nodes/57283430#57283430).

Answer (score 0):

get project_id and team members of all projects and store in object with project id and member_id.Then, get project_id of corresponding to member id of logged in user and retrieve the project if project exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can definitely do that,the below code tries to explain that.

```
var uid = UserId of user logged in    
ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if(doc.data().userID == uid  || doc.data().team['memberid1] == uid || doc.data().team['memberid2'] == uid) {
    \\ checks here whether user is authorized
  }
});
```

One thing to note here is, if there are more than 2 members then this code may not be optimized